# Can I keep 2 breeds of turtle together

Tags: multi-pet-families, turtles

I need to keep Indian Flapshell turtle along with Red ear slider turtle. Will it be ok to keep both together in one tank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red eared sliders in nature live alone. They meet only to reproduce and make little turtles once a year. All other times they meet as rival. 
I assume the red eared slider do not differ between another red eared slider and an indian flapshell, so I suppose to not hold them two together.