# One of my turtles hasn't grown and doesn't eat much, what should I do?

Tags: health, feeding, turtles, growing

I have 2 red eared sliders in a 20 gallon (76 liters) tank and I got them both 7 months ago. They were both the size of a 50 cent coin (about 3 cm) and the one hasn't grown past that size and only eats a couple bites of food. On the other hand, my second turtle is now 3 times the size and eats a lot. I just did research - I may be overfeeding him, but my little guy hasn't grown at all.

I am not sure what to do. Please let me know what advice you have.

Comment: Maybe this answer your question: [could I keep two turtles together?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/can-i-keep-2-breeds-of-turtle-together/26139?r=SearchResults#26139)